# Which other primary sources describe rainstorms in 1345–46 Italy?

Tags: italy, climate

Bryson's European tour comments on a rainstorm of very long duration in 1345. The best evidence for this I found in Villani's chronicle which described a rainstorm of three months' duration. **Which other primary sources describe rainstorms in 1345–46 Italy?**

---

Bill Bryson's ['Neither Here, Nor There'](https://books.google.ee/books?id=8opQCQLqsnAC&printsec=frontcover&dq=neither%20here%20nor%20there&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi8x6i5r7XqAhUtxKYKHU_0Bx8Q6AEwAHoECAYQAg#v=onepage&q=rained%20nonstop&f=false), a travel book about Europe, says:

> ... imagine what it must have been to be an Italian in the fourteenth century. For a start, in 1345 it rained non-stop for six months...

Bryson is not a historian nor does he need to be accurate to the letter, but I am curious as to how true this claim is. Though [the longest recorded rainstorm](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi626r1rLXqAhUHzaYKHSr5Cn0QFjABegQIDBAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fweather.com%2Fnews%2Fweather%2Fnews%2Frain-331-days-hawaii-record&usg=AOvVaw26wVQYTYygRLLqqrQX2ETn) is actually 331 days, I couldn't prove the 'six months' regarding 14th century Italy.

I did find a reference to these events in [Giovanni Villani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Villani)'s texts as translated in ['Medieval Italy: Texts and Translation'](https://books.google.ee/books?id=L2UUBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA22&dq=1345%20italy%20rain&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsj-LCrbXqAhWvy6YKHZarD30Q6AEwAHoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=1345%20italy%20rain&f=false):

> **In the aforesaid year of 1346, but beginning in October and November of 1345, because of too much rain, the sowing season was ruined, and then in April, May, and June of 1346 it rained ceaselessly, and there were such storms that for similar reasons the sowing of various crops was again ruined.**

This would at best be October and November as well as another wet April through June. In which case, Bryson may have indulged in poetic liberty. I didn't find other mentions, including [Wikipedia's 1345 in Italy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1345_in_Italy) which ignores these events entirely. Are there any other primary sources which commented on the weather in this period?

Comment: Bill Bryson probably meant that "metaphorically". I wouldn't take him by the word. Weather records don't reach that far, ofc.

Comment: "rained nonstop" may just mean "generally rainy weather with no significant breaks", not literal rain every second of the period.

Comment: Not a primary source and I don't read French but I see a relevant citation [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=DL2YDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA382) for this: Alexandre, Pierre. 1987. *Le climat en Europe au Moyen Âge. Contribution à l’histoire des variations climatiques de 1000 à 1425, d’après les sources narratives de l’Europe occidentale*,540–581. Paris:Éditions de l’École des HautesÉtudes en Sciences Sociales.